# Reduce a list of custom objects in java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two custom classes called `OrthogonalPoint` and `PolarPoint`.

```
public class OrthogonalPoint extends AbstractPoint<OrthogonalPoint> {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    // constructor, getters, ...
}
```

```
public class PolarPoint extends AbstractPoint<PolarPoint> {
    private double rho;
    private double theta;

    // constructor, getters, ...
}
```

Both extend an abstract class `AbstractPoint`.

```
public abstract class AbstractPoint<PointType extends AbstractPoint<PointType>> {

    public abstract double getX();

    public abstract double getY();

    public final double distance(PointType other) {
        // calculate distance between current point and other point
    }
}
```

Next, I have a class `Route`.

```
public class Route<T extends AbstractPoint<T>> {

    private final List<T> points = new ArrayList<>();

    public void appendPoint(T point) {
        this.points.add(point);
    }

    public double routeDistance() {
        // calculate total distance
    }
}
```

A route is an ordered number of points whose length is defined as the sum of the distances of the points in the sequence. So, if a route consists of three points (p1, p2, and p3) the distance of the route is `p1.distance(p2) + p2.distance(p3)`.
In the `routeDistance` function, I want to calculate this distance. I have tried something like

```
public double routeDistance() {
    return this.points.stream().reduce(0d, (point, point2) -> point.distance(point2));
}
```

But the body part of the lambda function is underlined red:

```
Bad return type in lambda expression: double cannot be converted to T
```

What would be the correct way to calculate the distance? I would like to use the reduce, but any solution is appreciated.

Comment: An orthogonal point is defined by 2 numbers (x and y); to find the point, start at the origin (not, usually, part of the definition of the point itself), and go 'x' distance on the x axis and 'y' distance on the y axis. A polar point is defined by 2 numbers (r and d); to find the point, start at the origin, and then go 'd' distance at an angle of r. In other words, __PolarPoint has absolutely no business having an x and y value here__. AbstractPoint should not have `.getX()` and `.getY()`, or if it should, PolarPoint's .getX() method will need to do quite a bit of math.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thank you for the comment, I made a simple copy-paste mistake. PolarPoint has class variables rho and theta (instead of x and y). ```.getX``` and ```.getY``` do quite a bit of math as you said. For example, ```.getX``` returns ```this.rho * Math.cos(this.theta)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reduce a `Point` to a `Double`. If you need to use an `ArrayList` then you can `mapToDouble` and then `sum()` (a special case of a reduction):

```
points.stream().skip(1).mapToDouble(point ->
        points.get(points.indexOf(point) - 1).distance(point)).sum();
```

or

```
points.stream().limit(points.size() - 1).mapToDouble(point ->
        point.distance(points.get(points.indexOf(point) + 1))).sum();
```

With `ÌntStream` you can do:

```
IntStream.range(1, points.size()).mapToDouble(i ->
        points.get(i - 1).distance(points.get(i))).sum();
```

or

```
IntStream.range(0, points.size() - 1).mapToDouble(i ->
        points.get(i).distance(points.get(i + 1))).sum();
```

Comment: All your examples work wonderfully! I will go with the first one :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you use reduce in the wrong way. Reduce doesn’t get two elements from your stream but the current accumulator and the current element and combine them to get the new accumulator. Here is a good tutorial on reduce: https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce
The easiest way here is to not use stream. As you need to keep the order of each two points, just use a regular for loop with i between 0 and n-1 to loop over all sub routes and sum the lengths.

Comment: I was endeed following the baeldung tutorial, unfortunately it doesn't have a useful example for me. I need to pass the next point in the list as a parameter to the current one. Maybe there is no way to solve this with streams, I will use the good old for-loop for now.